# Attempting to pass Linux command output into a variable

Tags: c, linux, bash

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readCmd(char* cmd) {
    FILE *fp;
    char path[1024];

    /* Open the command for reading. */
    fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", path);
    }
    /* close */
    pclose(fp);
    return path;
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
char* gp123;
char* gp124;


gp124=readCmd("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio124/direction");
gp123=readCmd("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio123/direction");
printf("123: %s \n124: %s \n",gp123,gp124);

}
```

With the following output:

```
out
in
123: in
124: in
```

As you can see, gpio pin 123 is set to 'in' and 124 is set to 'out'.

However, both gp123 and gp124 are being assigned 'in'. I am rusty with functions and C. Could you fellas help me out a little please?

More specifically, why is it failing to assign the returned value for each command I read? Is this a local/global variable issue?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* readCmd(char* cmd)
{
FILE *fp;
static char path[1024];

/* Open the command for reading. */
fp = popen(cmd, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    exit(1);
}

/* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", path);
}
/* close */
pclose(fp);
return path;
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char gp123[50];
    char gp124[50];
    char *answer;

    answer=readCmd("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio124/direction");
    sprintf(gp124, "%s", answer);
    answer=readCmd("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio123/direction");
    sprintf(gp123, "%s", answer);
    printf("123: %s \n124: %s \n",gp123,gp124);

}
```

This seems to work correctly, is there anything here I should change to be more correct?

Comment: try something like this:

char gp123[50];
char gp124[50];
char *answer;
answer=readCmd("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio124/direction");
sprintf(gp124, "%s", answer);
gp123=readCmd("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio123/direction");
sprintf(gp123, "%s", answer);

Comment: I think the return of readCmd() is unique, so when it returns to gp123, the value of variable gp124 is changed to gp123's value.

Comment: Hey, Kizz, could you please, give me a like in my comment as it worked for you? =)

Comment: I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: using the 'edited' version of the code:  there is no way the compiler did not produce any warnings.   The unused parameter: `argc` and the unused paramter: `argv[]`  will both cause the compiler to produce a warning.   When compiling, always enable all the warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )   To fix the compiler warnings declare main() as: `int main( void )`

Comment: for readability by us humans, please indent the code consistently.  I.E. indent after EVERY opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Comment: this line: `while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {` seems to indicate a mis-understanding of the fgets() function (suggest read the man page).  The line can be written as: `while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) ) {` and work correctly for all cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a pointer to automatic memory from a function. The path array only exists for the duration of the readCmd function (which should return char*, not an int).

To solve it, you can:

- declare the array static (or use a global array--pretty much the same thing) and embrace non-reenterability
- use the heap (malloc the array or use the GNU getline function)
- ask the caller to provide provide a pointer to where to save the output (its size should be passed in too)

Comment: I changed path to static and converted the function to a char*. This gave me the correct output and eliminated all compiler warnings.